# Connect to Proxy (SOCKS) Database in python

Tags: python, sql, database, sockets, socks

I am trying to connect to a database that needs **proxy (socks)** to be able to connect, if I use the proxy connection manually, I can connect, but I need to make the script connect to the **proxy (socks)** of the machine to make this `SELECT`

**SCRIPT**

```
import socket
import socks
import requests
import pymssql

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "138.34.133.155", 1080, True, 'user','password')
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

server = '172.43.56.89'
username = 'user'
password = 'password'
database = 'dbname'

conn = requests.get(pymssql.connect(host=server,user=username,password=password,database=database))

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT column FROM table")

row = cursor.fetchall()

conn.close()

for i in row:
    print(i)
```

**OUTPUT**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "connection.py", line 15, in
>   
>       conn = requests.get(pymssql.connect(host=server,user=username,password=password,database=database))
>   File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 642, in pymssql.connect
>   pymssql.OperationalError: (20009, 'DB-Lib error message 20009,
>   severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does
>   not exist (172.43.56.89:1433)\nNet-Lib error during Unknown error
>   (10060)\n')

Comment: `pymssql` is implemented in Cython. It does not use the `socket` module. There is no way the `socks` module to work for `pymssql`.

Comment: Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an option is to mount a local tunnelling sock with port forwarding, to map your database port and act as if your server where a localhost one.

It's really efficient if you're running your python script on a Unix computer.

Something like this system call (for a `3306` mariaDB) :

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 user@x.x.x.x
```

First, your run SSH, then, you tell him to enable a port forwarding from the `3306` port to the `localhost:3306` port of the server you connect through `user@IP`.

With this, every query from your `local machine:3306` will by send to your `MariaDB:3306` server, allowing you to use it as if you where on the server.

Comment: socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "ip", 1080, True, 'user','password')                                                                                     socket.socket = socks.socksocket

socket.socket(os.system('ssh ip'))

Comment: Returned error:

socket.error: [Errno 10047] An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used

Comment: @LuisHenrique I don't speech of a proxy, but directly as a tunnelling through a  [system command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-from-python) that run in background.

Comment: Okay, I get your idea, but I can't write it :/

Comment: @LuisHenrique are you on a unix/linux computer for the python (it's a server, a client or else?) ? If it's on windows, it'll probably be harder :/

Comment: I'm on a Red Hat linux machine

Comment: @LuisHenrique ok nice~; so, just try to run by hand in a console `ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 user@x.x.x.x` and change the port for the DB one, then try to run your `.py` as if your db was on your localhost, without proxy.

Comment: Ok, I will do the tests and add here, thank you very much!

Comment: @LuisHenrique Not very clear about this solution, could you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to hack into `pymssql` source code, there're external tools that redirect all TCP traffic over the socks proxy, such as [FreeCap](http://freecap.ru/eng/?p=whatis) for Windows, [RedSocks](https://github.com/darkk/redsocks) for Linux and [Proximac](https://github.com/csujedihy/proximac) for macOS.